# Unexpected behavior of numerical_approx

Tags: sage

The documentation of numerical_approx/n says "Return a numerical approximation of "self" with "prec" bits (or decimal "digits") of precision." so I expected it to be some kind of `rounding' and in particular to lose information.

But when running
t = 512.numerical_approx(digits=2)
print(t)
print(t-510)
I get
510.
2.0

The first print is exactly what I expected: An approximation of 512 using two decimal digits.
But why do I get 2.0 when printing (t-510)?

What am I missing here?
Is there another way to get the numerical approximation as a value (e.g., in order to calculate the approximation error)

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. The explanation is a bit complicated (and has a lot to do with MPFR, precision, exact integers, and whether using less-than-typical precision should also clear memory). But in short, it remembers that it came from a place with higher precision.

You can see this a bit more by looking at `tt = t.numerical_approx(digits=2)` and then `tt.__mpfr__()`, which shows `mpfr('512.0', 7)` (i.e. it remembers the previous value of 512 and the current precision).

Note however that the behavior is different for digits after the decimal point!

I actually don't know if there is a *good* way to get the apparent value, but you can convert from a string and back. For example,

```py
t = 512
tt = t.numerical_approx(digits=2)
apparent_tt = RR(str(tt))
print(float(tt))          # prints 512.0
print(float(apparent_tt)) # prints 510.0
```

But I advise caution --- there are dragons ahead!